# Asyncio returning "asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError()" in results list for most requests

Tags: rest, request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to get the response content for ~116000 requests using asyncio. For the most urls in the beginning I get the correct response(until the 20000th request) but after that I only get "asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError()" appended into my results list. Here is my code:

```
async def get_request(base_url:str, param_val:str, session:ClientSession, **kwargs) -> dict:
    LC_val = param_val.replace(' ', '%20') #String param for current url
    LC_curr_url = base_url.format(LC_val) #url formatted
    
    async with session.get(LC_curr_url, allow_redirects=False,timeout=200) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
    
        if 'parser' in base_url: #specific url that returns JSON
            data = await resp.json()
        else:
            data = await resp.text() #problematic url that returns XML -> to be converted to JSON later
    
    return data

async def main_requests(LC_url, LC_Param_vals, **kwargs):
    session_timeout = ClientTimeout(total=None,sock_connect=200,sock_read=200)    
    async with ClientSession(timeout=session_timeout) as LC_session:
        tasks = []
        for val in LC_Param_vals:
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_request(base_url=LC_url, param_val=val, session=LC_session))
            tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

...

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main_requests(tree_url, listCanonical))
```

I'm getting success with these functions when it comes to the first API that returns JSON. I thought that maybe because of the content of the second API is XML it might be the problem, but I'm not sure. I've already tested with TCPConnection limit and timeout parameters. I'm still learning asyncio but I got to the conclusion that this approach is the best one when it comes to thousands of requests as fast as possible, but I accept other suggestions to solve my problem. Thanks in advance!